# How is Lombok adding additional code to java classes during compile time?

Tags: java, lombok

This question is about at **how** during maven build process is Lombok adding additional code during compile process.

I have been using Lombok for some time and am to some extent aware about it's features. If i look back at few good starter tutorials for Lombok, like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-project-lombok), they advice on using the below dependency

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ... 
</dependencies>
```

*(For eclipse additional setup is required which is not my concern here. )*

1. So now with the above dependency added, if i do a **`mvn clean compile`**, will the boiler plate code be added to the generated class files.
2. If it does, how is this happening as there is no maven-compile stage plugin being added in the plugin section.

Above questions are based on the fact that Lombok code is added at compile time and not at run time.

Comment: it hooks into _internal_ details of `javac`. details that, I repeat, are _internal_. just like jdk-17 started to prohibit some things already, this will ultimately happen to Lombok too, imo. and the gap for Lombok is closing too, the first step towards that are `records`.

Comment: Hi, as far as I know, lombok uses [ Java Agents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). Eclipse require install Lombok, because it have his own agent, and it need to be replaced. There is also other technology for adding code during compiling: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html

Comment: In regular case (not IDE), if you have Lombok on classpath, the agent is changed to Lombok agent (2. this is why you don't need maven-compile stage for it), (1.) so ```mvn clean compile``` will add the code